# Get current time only and update it in android

Tags: java, android, time

I need to get the current time only (without data) in HH:mm format (eg. 14:20) and then update it every second or minute. I kinda get it with this code, but is it possible to convert it to a string?
And I need to pass the value "time" in a separate public String.
Any solution?
Thanks

```
public class ClockCounter extends TimerTask {

public long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void run(){
    time += 1000; //add 1 second to the time
    //convert ms time to viewable time and set MainActivity.text (textview) text to this.
}

public long getTime(){ return time; }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Got it working with a service that runs every second.

Comment: Hey what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to have a final variable `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

and you can get time with format in anywhere you want using this code:

```
String time = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: It works for getting the time once, but I need it to be working like a clock and update itself.

Comment: You can get the current time using this method at first. If you want something working like a clock, you just need to implement a `Thread` that has infinite loop : `sleep(1000)` and the time count adds 1 sec.

Answer (score 4):

Using liveData and coroutines:

```kotlin
 val currentTime = liveData {
        while (true){
            emit(Calendar.getInstance().time)
            kotlinx.coroutines.delay(1000)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do that like this :

```
private void clock() {
  final Handler hander = new Handler();
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hander.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              getTime();
              clock();
           }
        });
     }
  }).start();
}

void getTime() {
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Local.getDefault());
   textview.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below for get curent Clock with Hours ,Minutes and Seconds

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Your answer does not add much new looking at the other answers to this question. This is also a five-year-old question.